# How to use a jQuery dynamically created div in multiple (simple) functions

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I have a simple div created via jQuery....

```
var split = document.createElement('div');
    split.className ="item split";
    $(split).html('<strong>SPLITTER</strong>');
```

I want to use the same variable in a couple simple functions. However, it seems whenever I move the variable out of the function, I can only create the div once. Then all other instances fail to insert the div.

Test the snippet, it'll probably help explain better.

```js
// Variable is created WITHIN the click function
$('#divide_btn').on('click', function() {
  var split = document.createElement('div');
  split.className = "item split";
  $(split).html('<strong>SPLITTER</strong>');

  $(split).hide(function() {
    //stuff
  }).insertAfter('.moved:last').slideDown(300);
});


// Variable is created OUTSIDE the click function.
var split2 = document.createElement('div');
split2.className = "item split";
$(split2).html('<strong>SPLITTER 2</strong>');


$('#divide_btn2').on('click', function() {
  $(split2).hide(function() {
    //stuff
  }).insertAfter('.moved:last').slideDown(300);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.item,
.moved,
.split {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #eee;
}
.moved {
  background: #fee;
}
.split {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span id="divide_btn">click for internal variable</span><span id="divide_btn2">click for external variable</span>
</p>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item moved">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Note the difference, for the "internal" button the div is created *within* the click function and every time I click a new div is created (as expected).

For the "external" button the variable is created *outside* the click function and only ONE div can be created.

**Is there a way to use an external variable for a dynamic div and be able to utilize that variable in functions the same way functions operate if the variable was internal?**

I'm seeking the functionality of the "internal" button.. but I want to use the *same variable* across *all* my functions and avoid the need to replicate the div creation in every single function where it's needed.

(Note the dynamic div never changes... so there's no need to edit the variable once it's set.)

Comment: I realize the slide effect isn't working here, but that' s largely irrelevant.

Comment: does this help [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qdLLuqy/1/) ?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity yes it does.. please post that as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/veqy7tju/)

```js
// Variable is created WITHIN the click function
$('#divide_btn').on('click', function() {
  var split = document.createElement('div');
  split.className = "item split";
  $(split).html('<strong>SPLITTER</strong>');

  $(split).hide(function() {
    //stuff
  }).insertAfter('.moved:last').slideDown(300);
});


// Variable is created OUTSIDE the click function.
function createSplit2() {
  var split2 = document.createElement('div');
  split2.className = "item split";
  $(split2).html('<strong>SPLITTER 2</strong>').hide();
  return $(split2);
}

$('#divide_btn2').on('click', function() {
  createSplit2().insertAfter('.moved:last').slideDown(300);
});
```

```css
body { padding: 20px; }
span { display: inline-block; margin: 5px; background: #aaa; color: #eee; padding: 5px 10px;}
.item, .moved, .split { padding: 5px 10px; margin: 3px; background: #eee; }
.moved { background: #fee; }
.split { background: #aaa; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span id="divide_btn">click for internal variable</span><span id="divide_btn2">click for external variable</span>
</p>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item moved">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this fails when I need to add functions to the div. I need the div to be created, then allow actions upon it. **This function works great if I only wanted the div created**, but I can't seem to work out how to add additional jq functions.

Comment: Oh, so basically same problem with the internal div creating? ok let me try something and see if it could help

Comment: Actually check the click function in my original snippet, you can see I then hide, insert, and slide the dynamic div.. I need to be able to do that still. The other answer suggesting cloning works.. but I'm always open to better implementation!

Comment: I worked it out... see here: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5qdLLuqy/3/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed, another implementation that might work is as in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qdLLuqy/5/)

Comment: but aren't you inserting it *twice* in this https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5qdLLuqy/3/ ?

Comment: Yeah I just notice that. If I remove the insert from the creation function, it fails. It inserts in different locations... so... still playing with things.

Comment: Yup, that's got it... and tested with additional functionality... https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5qdLLuqy/9/  THANKS!

Comment: You so welcome, I've updated the answer but you could keep @MohammadAkbari  answer checked if you like. Anyways I'm glad it helped and enjoy coding!

Comment: Nope, you deserve the √ I can use this general principal well beyond cloning and it'll come in more handy than you think :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Get clone from split2

```js
// Variable is created WITHIN the click function
$('#divide_btn').on('click', function () {
    var split = document.createElement('div');
    split.className ="item split";
    $(split).html('<strong>SPLITTER</strong>');
    
    $(split).hide(function() {
        //stuff
     }).insertAfter('.moved:last').slideDown(300);
   });



// Variable is created OUTSIDE the click function.

var split2 = document.createElement('div');
split2.className ="item split";
$(split2).html('<strong>SPLITTER 2</strong>');

$( '#divide_btn2' ).on('click', function () {
$(split2).clone().hide(function() { // Get clone from split2 *********
                      //stuff
    }).insertAfter('.moved:last').slideDown(300);
   });
```

```css
body { padding: 0 20px; margin:0;}
span { display: inline-block; margin: 5px; background: #aaa; color: #eee; padding: 5px 10px;}

.item, .moved, .split { padding: 5px 10px; margin: 3px; background: #eee; }

.moved { background: #fee; }

.split { background: #aaa; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span id="divide_btn">click for internal variable</span><span id="divide_btn2">click for external variable</span></p>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item moved">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: duh.. why didn't I think of cloning.. works wonderfully in any function I need it. Thank you. (I removed the original snippet from your answer so as not to confuse matters.)